# Primefaces p:tabView: Value of selectOneMenu lost

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, myfaces

I have a problem when I use a p:tabView with dynamic="true", and there is a h:selectOneMenu on one tab, and on the other is a commandLink which is ajax="false". After clicking to the commandLink twice the value of the selectOneMenu is lost.

This problem does not occur when the tabView is dynamic="false".

The value of the h:inputText is not lost, but I see the following warning in the logfile:

```
org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils decodeUIInput WARNING: There should always be a submitted value for an input if it is rendered, its form issubmitted, and it was not originally rendered disabled or read-only.  You cannot submit a form after disabling an input element via javascript.  Consider setting read-only to true instead or resetting the disabled value back to false prior to form submission. Component : {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /form/regional/region.xhtml][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlBody,Id: j_id_5][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: TestForm][Class: org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView,Id: tabviewTest][Class: org.primefaces.component.tabview.Tab,Id: j_id_8][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText,Id: j_id_f]}
```

Here is the form:

```
  <p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="true" id="tabviewTest">
     <p:tab title="Tab 1">
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{Region.dropDownValue}" id="dropDown">
           <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue=""/>
           <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"/>
           <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2"/>
           <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3"/>
           <f:selectItem itemLabel="4" itemValue="4"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:inputText value="#{Region.inputValue}" />
     </p:tab>
     <p:tab title="Tab 2">
        <p:commandLink ajax="false" 
                       id="link" 
                       value="Test" 
                       actionListener="#{Region.someActionMethod}" />
     </p:tab>

  </p:tabView>
```

And here the Bean:

```
public class Region  {

    private Integer dropDownValue = 3;
    private String inputValue = "Test";

    public void someActionMethod(ActionEvent ev) {
        System.out.println("someActionMethod called");
    }

    public Integer getDropDownValue() {
        return dropDownValue;
    }

    public void setDropDownValue(Integer dropDownValue) {
        this.dropDownValue = dropDownValue;
    }

    public String getInputValue() {
        return inputValue;
    }

    public void setInputValue(String inputValue) {
        this.inputValue = inputValue;
    }  
}
```

My Environment: Primefaces 5.0/5.1.RC1, Myfaces 2.1/2.2, Tomact 7

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by the "the value is lost"? Do you mean the value is reset to the default? Or is it blank?

Comment: See, `cache="true"` and `dynamic="true"` are somewhat contradictory IMO. Set `cache="true"` and try again

Comment: Sorry, I meant set `cache="false"`

Comment: It does not work with `cache="false"` - I have already tried that.

Comment: Well you already have your answer. Why can't you have `dynamic="false"`?

Comment: I use `dynamic="false"`as workaround for the moment - but this cannot be the final solution because performance is much better with `dynamic="true"`. (There are a lot of tabs and elements in the real application)

Answer (score 2):

What scope does your ManagedBean have?

When you use a RequestScope you are not able to submit your selectOneMenu with an UICommand component like p:commandLink when you set the ajax attribute to false. The changes are lost in this case.

Here are two possibilities to fix your problem:

**Attempt 1: Set your Bean ViewScoped:**
In most cases this will work. If you must use special annotations to annotate your beans (like Apache DeltaSpike @ViewAccessScoped for example), try to separate your bean into View and Controller beans, annotating the View with just simple @ViewScope and keeping all the values in it.

**Attempt 2: Remove ajax="false" from p:commandLink:**
This will work if your use-case allows it. For example, downloading a file with PrimeFaces will require explicit declaration that the ajax is not to be used, so this solution will not be applicable.

Comment: Regarding 1: The ManageBean is session scoped, so that is not the reason.

Comment: Regarding 2: The code I have posted is simplified, in real application I have some components which trigger a full page submit (so using Ajax is not possible)

Comment: Hm okay. For me your example worked fine if i use one of this attempts. Propably the reason of your problem come from the warning of your inputField. I think it is also not a normal behaviour that the value of the selectMenu gets lost and the value of the inputField stays when they are both in the same form. Have you tried to debug your application with a PhaseListener?

Answer (score 0):

add ajax listener

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{Region.dropDownValue}" id="dropDown">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue=""/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2"/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3"/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="4" itemValue="4"/>
       <p:ajax event="change" update="@this"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```